# IntelliSense included in Python's Microsoft Extension vs Visual Studio IntelliCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellicode

[IntelliSense Autocomplete](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense)

vs

[Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)

Should I avoid using Visual Studio IntelliCode when using default IntelliSense?

What's the difference between them? What are advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a software engineer on the IntelliCode team. IntelliCode is meant to augment the default IntelliSense experience and save you time by putting what you're most likely to use at the top of your completion list. IntelliCode recommendations are based on thousands of open source projects on GitHub.